# unable to see Task tracker and Jobtracker after Hadoop single node installation 2.5.1

Tags: hadoop

Iam new to Hadoop 2.5.1. As i have already installed Hadoop 1.0.4 previously, i thought installation process would be same so followed following tutorial.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Every thing was fine, even i have given these settings in core-site.xml

```
<name>fs.default.name</name>

  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
```

But i have seen in several sites this value as 9000.

And also changes in yarn.xml.

Still everything works fine when i run a mapreduce job. But my question is

when i run command jps it gives me this output..

```
hduser@secondmaster:~$ jps

5178 ResourceManager

5038 SecondaryNameNode

4863 DataNode

5301 NodeManager

4719 NameNode

6683 Jps
```

I dont see task tracker and job tracker in jps. Where are these demons running.
And without these deamons how am i able to run Mapreduce job.

Thanks,

Sreelatha K.

Answer (score 0):

From hadoop version hadoop 2.0 onwards, default processing framework has been changed to YARN from Classic Mapreduce. You are using YARN, where you cannot see Jobtracker, Tasker in YARN. Jobtracker and Tasktracker is replaced by Resource manager and Nodemanager respectively in YARN.

But still you have an option to use Classic Mapreduce framework instead of YARN.

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop 2 there is an alternative method to run MapReduce jobs, called YARN. Since you have made changes in yarn.xml, MapReduce processing happens using YARN, not using the traditional MapReduce framework. That's probably be the reason why you don't see TaskTracker and JobTracker listed after executing the jps command. Note that ResourceManager and NodeManager are the daemons for YARN.

Answer (score 0):

YARN is next generation of Resource Manager who can able to integrate with Apache spark, storm and many more tools you can use to write map-reduce jobs