# I have a confusion with hadoop 2.7. After I run the start-all.sh, I haven't find jobtracker and tasktracker in the jps list, why?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have a confusion with `hadoop 2.7`.

After I run the `start-all.sh`, I type the `jps` command, but I haven't find `jobtracker` and `tasktracker` in the list, why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This entirely depends on how you setup your configuration. There are log files and errors probably that you should include in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hadoop-2.7.2, mapreduce framework changed to YARN. So you can find Resourcemanager and Nodemanager instead of jobtracker and tasktracker.

Similar Questions

[unable to see Task tracker and Jobtracker after Hadoop single node installation 2.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759422/unable-to-see-task-tracker-and-jobtracker-after-hadoop-single-node-installation)

For technical information, check the below link

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/